# javascript movecontent from div with tags

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div which contains text and some html codes.
I want to move the content ( text and codes ) from this div to textarea.
I have movecontent javascript, but it moves only text..
Can anyone help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MoveContent () {
        var srcObj = document.getElementById ("src");
        var destObj = document.getElementById ("dest");

        if (document.createRange) {     // all browsers, except IE before version 9
            var rangeObj = document.createRange ();
            rangeObj.selectNodeContents (srcObj);
            var documentFragment = rangeObj.extractContents ();
            destObj.appendChild (documentFragment);
        }
    }
</script>
          </head>
     <body>
     <div id="src" style="background-color:#e0a0b0; width:300px; height:50px;">The <br>    <b>contents</b> of the <i>source</i> element.</div>
   <textarea id="dest" style="width: 500px; height:100px;"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="MoveContent ();">Move the contents!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for that one:

```
destObj.value = documentFragment.innerHTML;
```

You normally don't append content to a `<textarea>`, as they may only contain CDATA. Just use the `.value` property, like with `<input>` elements. Also, I'm not sure for what exactly you need that `documentRange`, wouldn't `srcObj.innerHTML` do it as well?

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MMKub/)

Comment: `<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

function MoveContent() {
    var srcObj = document.getElementById("src");
    var destObj = document.getElementById("dest");
    destObj.value = srcObj.innerHTML;
}
//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="src" style="background-color:#e0a0b0; width:300px; height:50px;">The <br>    <b>contents</b> of the <i>source</i> element.</div>
   <textarea id="dest" style="width: 500px; height:100px;"></textarea>
<button onclick="MoveContent ();">Move the contents!</button>​`